# Dualism & Non-dualism

Tags: philosophy, teaching, darshan

What's the philosophical difference between various schools of Vedanta philosophy? According to dualism (Dvaita), Jivatma and Parmatma are two different things; non-dualism (Advaita)- Jivatma and Parmatma are same, and also there are others schools viz., Dvaitadvaita, Vishistadvaita, Upadhika, Shuddhadvaita, Achintya, and Neo-Vedanta. So, what's the basic difference among these schools? Please explain me!

Comment: The difference has to be in "Stage of Perceiving the truth". Hence they are Not related as competitors, but as levels of understandings. *Dvaita* perceives truth at outer (i.e. physical/body) level. *Advaita* perceives it at inner (i.e. soul) level. *Advaita* makes you much closer to God in no time but to retain that feeling continuously is not easy. *Dvaita* keeps you in current reality to strive for God. While *Advaita* is easy to start with, *Bhakti* is better progressed with *Dvaita*. There are some intermediate schools too. Consider this as answer without sources.